# How to trigger native event in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a custom input tag, `PhoneInput`. It has 3 inputs inside, so I need to parse them, and concat back to string.
I want to pass in `onChange` callback `SyntheticEvent`, like React does. So I need to create hidden input:

`<input onChange={this.props.onChange} value={this.state.value}/>`

But when I change state, event didn't triggers. How to do it right?
http://jsbin.com/bahuyuriqa/1 - here is example.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: Keep your development tools open and click while watching the console. If you see an error then, it mght indicate something about then state of this.props.onChange() at the time of the click.

Answer (score 2):

Change events, it seems, are only fired from user input.  Is there a specific reason you would need an onChange handler on the hidden input?  If you do need access to the native event from the [synthetic event](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html), you can simply access it via `e.nativeEvent`